# GPA is returning error after upgrade from 16.04LTS to 18.10

Tags: upgrade, encryption, gnupg

I've used GPA (GNU Privacy Assistant) successfully for years starting from 12.10 to 16.04LTS. Yesterday I made update to 18.04LTS and then to 18.10 and find that it cannot encrypt or decrypt any file in its File Manager. The following error is displayed instead:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwoz3.png)

Comment: It seems that issue is related to "message integrity protection" (?). When I tried to decrypt the same file from command line using gpg, the following error is displayed: gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected
gpg: Hint: If this message was created before the year 2003 it is
     likely that this message is legitimate.  This is because back
     then integrity protection was not widely used.
gpg: Use the option '--ignore-mdc-error' to decrypt anyway.
gpg: decryption forced to fail!

Comment: Additionally, freshly encrypted file (i.e. using GPA on 18.10) can be decrypted without problem.